# LaCie external disk setup assistant immediately quits unexpectedly on Mac OS X 10.7

Tags: macos, hard-drive, external-disk, error

In order to upgrade the operating system on my old 2011 MacBook Air running macOS 10.7, I first wanted to back up the contents of the hard drive to an external disk. I already had a fresh, unused LaCie 4TB external disk lying around so I figured that would be sufficient.

When I plugged the cable into the laptop, the disk mounted successfully and the icon appeared upon the desktop. However, when I opened the disk and tried to run the necessary startup tool, it always quits unexpectedly within 1 second of being started.

Does anyone know if there is a workaround for this issue?

Comment: What "necessary startup tool" ?

Comment: Have you contacted LaCie?

Comment: You don't need to use third party tools.  Use /applications/utilities/disk utility.  use carbon copy cloner, ccc, to copy.